# Example of smallest nonzero eigenvalue of Laplace-Beltrami operator having multiplicity 1.

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

I would very much appreciate a simple example of a compact Riemannian manifold for which the eigenspace corresponding to the smallest nonzero eigenvalue of the Laplace-Beltrami operator is one-dimensional.

The context is: I am writing a paper about a special case of [this inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186428/is-the-heat-kernel-more-spread-out-with-a-smaller-metric). The inequality doesn't hold whenever the condition I am asking about holds, and so I would like to include a section about how the general case fails.